# Save a dynamic page to a file or web archive

Tags: python, python-2.7, web, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I want to save a page on my disk (to open it even off-line). If the page is very basic: some text, few images, few links etc. I have no problem. But if I want to save a page like `https://www.python.org/` I have a lot of probles with the grpahics.
I was trying:

```
htmldata = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.python.org/').read()
f = open('myfile.html','w')
f.write(htmldata)
f.close()
```

But when I open my file I have:
[image]

Even if I try to save any `img` from page (using bs4 to find them), it found only one image and the page in my file is still the same.
So how can I save a page to open it off-line. Maybe it shouldn't be a .html file but something else?

Answer (score 3):

You have to find in HTML all urls to images, css, js and download them and then change that ulrs in HTML and set files location on your disk.

BTW: Maybe new urls will need `file://` prefix.

BTW: Some images can be defined in CSS or JS files. So you would need to find urls in CSS and JS, download them and change urls in CSS and JS as in HTML.

Comment: @furus But how I should change this url - I should made them as relative path or something else? And if I will find all elements, dowload them, then I need to change that url in the html which I will save? Can you give an example (it can be a totally random or made up example)

Comment: Use `Save page as` in browse and see how it change urls in HTML file. You will have to do the same.

Comment: If you save image in the same folder with HTML file then you can use `src="image.jpg"`. if you download to `subfolder` then you need `src="subfolder/image.jpg`. I don't remeber if you will need add `file://` prefix - `src="file://image.jpg` and `src="file://subfolder/image.jpg`

Comment: I never try to do this with Scrapy - but Scrapy can do many things :)